# How to normalize a list of eigenvectors?

Tags: eigenvalues

Here is a simple eigenvector problem solution

```
m = {{2, Sqrt[15]}, {Sqrt[15], 4}};
v = Eigenvectors[m]
```

However, the list of vectors v is not normalized. The command

```
Normalize[v]
```

returns an error. It seems Normalize doesn't want a list of vectors. The following works just fine:

```
u = Table[Normalize[v[[i]]], {i, 2}];
```

...but it seems clunky to me. I found an alternate way to use `Normalize` with a second argument, namely

```
Normalize[v, Norm]
```

but the list of vectors returned is not the same as u.

Is there something better than using `Table` to normalize the list of eigenvectors?

Comment: try `Normalize /@ v`?

Answer (score 10):

Here's a range of incremental improvements:

```
Table[Normalize[v[[i]]], {i, 2}]

Table[Normalize[v[[i]]], {i, Length[v]}] (* like a for loop in other languages *)

Table[Normalize[ev], {ev, v}] (* like a for each loop in other languages *)

Map[Normalize, v]

Normalize /@ v (* shorthand for Map *)
```

Look up [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) and all the syntaxes of [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) and read this:

- https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/applying-functions/

Note that `Eigenvectors` will return normalized eigenvectors if its input are floating point numbers, but not if the input is exact.  `Eigenvactors@N[m]` gives a normalized approximate result because `N[m]` is floating point.  `Eigenvalues[m]` doesn't because `m` is exact.

---

`Normalize[v, Norm]` does not do what you think it is doing.  `Normalize[vector, function]` simply computes `vector / function[vector]`.  In your case it uses `Norm[v]`, which is a *matrix norm*, not a vector norm.

Comment: What is `ev`? eigenvalues?

Comment: @Alex It is the name of the iterator used in `Table`. It is not a global variable.

Answer (score 8):

`Normalize` is not a `Listable` function, which means that you cannot expect it to act on a list of arguments in the same way that it acts on an argument. That is why you have to `Map` its action into the list of vectors.

So as @kglr writes in the comments, `Map[Normalize,v]`, or equivalently `Normalize/@v`, will do the job:

```
Normalize /@ {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}

(* {{1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}, {1/Sqrt[2], -(1/Sqrt[2])}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you both very much. This is just what I needed.

Comment: Another way to think about your problem (and the answers) is that you were trying to normalize a *matrix*.  Instead you want to normalize *each* row (vector) in the matrix.  Thus you have to map `Normalize` to each of the rows.