# Eigenvectors of Hermitian matrices

Tags: matrix, physics, eigenvalues

I asked a similar question in the physics stack exchange, but realized my question is probably more suited here.

For any Hermitian matrix $H = H^{\dagger}$ we can write $H = P DP^{\dagger}$ where $P$ is the matrix containing the eigenvectors and $D$ is the matrix containing the eigenvalues on the diagonal. In this case $P^{-1} =P^{\dagger}$ and $P^{\dagger}$ means the Hermitian conjugate.

So I wanted to do this for a specific matrix of the form

```
h = {{x, -d}, {- d, -x}}
```

where $x$ and $d$ are both real.

I wrote

```
Eigensystem[h]
```

and obtained

```
{-(x+ Sqrt[d^2 + x^2])/d,1} and {(-x+ Sqrt[d^2 + x^2])/d,1}
```

as eigenvectors and

```
Sqrt[d^2 + x^2] and -Sqrt[d^2 + x^2]
```

as the corresponding eigenvalues.

However, if we now use the eigenvectors to form the matrix $P$

```
p = {
{-(x+ Sqrt[d^2 + x^2])/d,(-x+ Sqrt[d^2 + x^2])/d },
{1,1}
}
```

we see that $P$ does not satisfy $P^{-1} \neq P^{\dagger}$.

In physics I think this is a big deal, because it means that your eigenstates does not satisfy the necessary (anti)commutation relations.

My question is:
How can I get mathematica to give me the eigenvectors that makes sure $P^{-1} = P^{\dagger}$?

I'm asking this question because I eventually want to generalize this procedure to a hermitian block diagonal $8 \times 8$ matrix.

In my case I think my normalized eigenvectors should be $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$ where

$u^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{\xi^2 + \Delta^2}} \right)$,
$v^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{\xi^2 + \Delta^2}} \right)$

However, I can't obtain this by just writing

```
FullSimplify[Normalize[{-(x+ Sqrt[d^2 + x^2])/d,1}]]
```

Is there an easy way to simplify this using Mathematica?

Comment: Normalize the eigenvectors. (This is done on approximate numeric matrices by `Eigensystem[]` but not on symbolic or exact matrices. See "Details and Options" of the documentation for `Eigensystem`, 2nd & 3rd points.)

Comment: Related: [(72941)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72941), [(79862)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79862), [(139216)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139216), [(151547)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/151547)